# Split row into several rows while keeping cells

Tags: excel

I have one big row in Excel and want to split the row into a new row every third cell.

This is a solution i found, but this drops everything in one cell after I run the code: [Split one row into several rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752659/split-one-row-into-several-rows)

I want to split into a new row every third cell, but keep the cells seperate. How to get this done? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO @Max! Please consider to post exemples of what you are trying to achieve as well as what you came with. Take a little time to look at [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesPL! The question is just that simple. Got one row, want to split it every third cell. See the link to the other SO topic for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in row **1**, pick a cell, say **A3** and enter:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,0,COLUMNS($A:A)+3*(ROWS($1:1)-1))
```

copy this both across and downward:

[image]

As you see, the data in the original row is distributed into multiple rows, three cells at a time.  The original cells are not changed.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your answer. This looks exactly how i want to have it, but i'm geting an error as seen at https://prnt.sc/nohzi8 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Max It appears that you must use non-English function-names; probably German or Dutch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. 